# Using Gson deserilization with arbitrary class type

Tags: json, list, casting, gson

I use a REST service that responds in json with messages like this:

```
{
   "statusMessage":{
      "message":"my message",
      "error":false
   },
   "data":null
}
```

Field `data` is an array, sometimes null, sometimes fill with instances of one class (like Partner, Department, Building,... only one type of them).

In my Java app, I have a `ServerResponse` class and it looks like:

```
public class ServerResponse {

    private StatusMessage statusMessage;
    private List<Object> data;

    public ServerResponse(StatusMessage statusMessage, List<Object> data) {
        this.statusMessage = statusMessage;
        this.data = data;
    }
    ...
}
```

When `data` is null, there is no problem, but when it fills with some objects, I don't know how to deserialize it. If I use:

`response = gson.fromJson(result, ServerResponse.class);`

I can't cast or use the list of objects in `data`. Furthermore, if I declare the field data in Java like this:

```
private List<Department> data;
```

It works fine with `Department` type, but, as might be expected, throws error with others types. I'm stuck...

Comment: If the JSON being returned is that bad, you're pretty much out of luck when it comes to deserializing it to a Java class/object. At least not without hacky nonsense and casting to/from `Object`. You're better off simply parsing the JSON and extracting the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify type for `data`, ie you use `List<Object>` as now, your will get at leas a list of maps (and map can contains again list or maps depending on content).

If you can discriminate type of object by the content, you can write a simple custom deserializer like asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588020/gson-serialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects/19600090#19600090) (check `isA` field)