# Reconstruct child object from JSON

Tags: java, json, inheritance, vector, gson

I have a parent class, say class P and three child classes, say C1, C2 and C3. I have a `type` variable in class P to determine the type of child class. I have a vector of P which contains several instances of C1, C2 and C3 and I convert that vector object to JSON using Gson library. When i reconstruct the vector from JSON using Gson giving the type as Vector<P> (I use TypeToken for that) i get a vector of class P, but when I cast the P object to any of the child class depending on the `type` variable I get ClassCastException. How can I achieve this without exception??

```
Type t = new TypeToken<Vector<P>>() {}.getType();
Vector ps=(Vector<P>)gson.fromJson(jsonString,t);
for(P pObj : ps ) {
    if(pObj.type == 1) {
        C1 cObj=(C1)pObj;
    }
    else if(pObj.type == 2) {
        C2 cObj=(C2)pObj;
    }
    else if(pObj.type == 3) {
        C3 cObj=(C3)pObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not into Gson but I use simplejson. Anyhow, my experience with this kind of code suggests that the json object unmarshalling always gives us java `Object`s in this way. So I normally use List to Array and use those objects from there. in javascript, since objects are typeless, these type of codes work good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deserialize, you get a vector of P, so you can't cast to base class since concrete class is P (and not C[1-3] for every object in `Vector`. I think that the only chance for you to get the desired result is to write your own deserializer.

I wrote a quite detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588020/gson-serialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects/19600090#19600090) that has same concepts. It uses a `List` instead of a `Vector` (more flexible) and uses a string to match base class. For the rest is exactly the way you should proceed.

Comment: Let me know if you understand how to map your problem to the other answer I gave.