# How do I deserialize generic object "T" with Gson?

Tags: java, android, generics, gson

I know it's a frequently asked question, but after searching for two hours I'm asking here if there's a solution. I need to implement a third party interface that serializes and deserializes objects in an Android app. I'd like to use Gson to achieve this.
The methods are the following:

```
@Override
public byte[] serialize(Object object) throws IOException {
    return new Gson().toJson(object).getBytes();
}

@Override
public <T extends Job> T deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // problem here
}
```

I can't use something like this:

```
gson.fromJson(responseBody, new TypeToken<T>() {}.getType());
```

Because it returns an object of type `LinkedTreeMap`.
Gson needs the Class of the object, but I've only this `T` (I come from the .net world, where generics are more "developer friendly").

Is it possible to obtain the original class of `T` in this scenario?

Comment: Unlikely.  What you could do is have the `TypeToken` be another argument to `deserialize` and force the caller of `deserialize` to declare what type they expect.  Otherwise, no, you can't deserialize an object of an unknown type with Gson.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I can't change neither the method signature nor the caller. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Then you're...pretty much SOL.  You'll need to be specific for which object type you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already discussed in the comments, it's not possible for Gson to be **really brilliant** and figure out what the original object was. If you spend 5 minutes thinking about how that would have to work, you'll realize it's impossible.

However, you might be able to, in a **custom** deserializer, analyze the `Json` and figure out what type it was supposed to be. Gson already has [`RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java) for this. See this discussion for a working example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22081826/1768232

Basically, you can use this factory to specify the type in the json itself, (it will look like `"type":"typename"`, which will make it possible for you to do the deserialization.

If modifying the json is not an option, you can *still* write a custom deserializer to analyze the json and attempt to figure out what type it's supposed to be, but that logic is much more difficult.

Comment: uh, thank you! this may be a solution, I can do what I want with the json. I'll try it soon.