# GSon not serializing properly with inheritance

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I am a newbie to Gson library, not sure why this object to json converter works weird. I have  code something similar to the below

```
public class A implements Serializable{
    @Expose
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

public class B extends A implements Serializable{
    @Expose
    private int x;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}

 public class MainclassTester{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    public B b = new B();
    b.setName("Point");
    b.setX(2);
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(b));

   }
 }
```

I want the output to be something like this

```
{
"name":'Point',
 "x":2
}
```

but I get the output

```
{
 "name":'Point'
 }
```

My subclass variables are not serialized properly.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588020/gson-serialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects/22081826#22081826

Comment: which version are you using:???  wih gson 2.7 is working fine!

Comment: Tried 2.6.2 and working fine, btw, you don't use `public` for variable inside a method: `public B b = new B();`

Answer (score 0):

You need annotate your class with expose, just for field to be exposed.
So do you need erase expose before `private int x;`.

To supress a field it is necessary to instantiate a Gson with a `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation` modifier.

```
GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```