# Serialization of an Object having a polymorphic list of different type

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, gson

I am trying to build a custom App to control Smart Home devices utilizing the Tasmota firmware and MQTT. Primarily that is smart lights at the moment. Therefore I have a `Device` class with children depending on the type of the device. Each device stores a `DeviceState` which is updated due to any changes made through the app. So the `DeviceState` is always the current state of the device. Depending on the device I need different DeviceStates, so again there is one superclass and subclass.
Now i want to store scenes with an ArrayList of DeviceStates to first store and than recreate certain light atmospheres. Therefore there is a class called Scene holding basic information and the described ArrayList.
To Store those lists i am using the Gson library in Android. My question is now how to be able to save those scenes objects with a polymorphic list inside.

I have followed this stackoverflow post: [Gson serialize a list of polymorphic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588020/gson-serialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects) to save my devices as an Json String using the Gson library and a custom serializer / deserializer. But now Hence DeviceState doesn´t extend Scene I can´t use one serializer to create a String out of the Scene object. And if i would extend DeviceState to Scene, the DeviceState class would declare multiple JSON fields with the same name, because I am using "typeName" to differentiate those classes.

So basically i am getting the errors, that DeviceState doesn´t extend Scene or that DeviceState declares multiple JSON fields named "typeName".

```
public class Scene{

        private ArrayList<DeviceState> states;
        private String name;
        private String room;
        private String typeName;

        public ArrayList<Scene> sceneList = new ArrayList<>();

        public Scene(){


        }

        public Scene(String pName, String pRoom) {
            name = pName;
            room = pRoom;

            states = new ArrayList<>();

            typeName = "Scene";
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getRoom() {
            return room;
        }

        public void addDevice(Device d) {
            states.add(d.getState());
        }

        public void execute() {
            System.out.println(states.size());
        }

        public String getTypeName(){
            return typeName;
        }
    }
```

```
public class DeviceState {

    private String typeName;
    private String deviceTopic;

    public static final String RGBWLightState = "RGBWLightState";
    public static final String Default = "DeviceState";

    public DeviceState(String pTypeName, String pDeviceTopic){
        typeName = pTypeName;
        deviceTopic = pDeviceTopic;
    }

    public DeviceState(){
        typeName = Default;
    }


    public String getTypeName() {
        return typeName;
    }
}
```

```
public class CustomSceneSerializer implements JsonSerializer<ArrayList<Scene>> {

    private static Map<String, Class> map = new TreeMap<>();

    static {
        map.put(DeviceState.RGBWLightState, RGBWLightState.class);
        map.put(DeviceState.Default, DeviceState.class);
        map.put("Scene", Scene.class);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(ArrayList<Scene> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {

        if(src == null) {
            return null;
        }else{
            JsonArray ja = new JsonArray();
            for(Scene s : src){
                Class c = map.get(s.getTypeName());
                if(c == null){
                    throw new RuntimeException("Unkown class: " + s.getTypeName());
                }
                    ja.add(context.serialize(s, c));
            }
            return ja;
        }
    }

}
```

```
public class CustomSceneDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<Scene>> {

    private static Map<String, Class> map = new TreeMap<>();


    static {
        map.put(DeviceState.RGBWLightState, RGBWLightState.class);
        map.put(DeviceState.Default, DeviceState.class);
        map.put("Scene", Scene.class);
    }


    @Override
    public List<Scene> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList<Scene>();
        JsonArray ja = json.getAsJsonArray();

        for (JsonElement je : ja) {

            String type = je.getAsJsonObject().get("typeName").getAsString();
            Class c = map.get(type);
            if (c == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknow class: " + type);
            list.add(context.deserialize(je, c));
        }

        return list;
    }


}
```

To save the Object holding a list of those objects I am using:

```
String json = preferences.getString("scene_holder", "");

GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();

List<Scene> al = new ArrayList<>();

gb.registerTypeAdapter(al.getClass(), new CustomSceneDeserializer());
gb.registerTypeAdapter(al.getClass(), new CustomSceneSerializer());
Gson gson = gb.create();

System.out.println(list.size());
list.get(0).execute();
System.out.println(json);

if (!(json.equals(""))) {

    Scene result = gson.fromJson(json, Scene.class);

    System.out.println(result.sceneList.size());

    result.sceneList = list;

    System.out.println(result.sceneList.size());

    editor.putString("scene_holder", gson.toJson(result)).commit();
} else {
    Scene scene = new Scene();

    scene.sceneList = list;

    editor.putString("scene_holder", gson.toJson(scene)).commit();
}
```