# Consuming polymorphic json "data: { put_anything_here }" with Gson & Retrofit

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I'm not sure if polymorphic is the right term to use so my apologies.

I'm working with the following API:

**Request body**:

```json
{
    "user_id": "user_id",
    "command": "submit_document",
}
```

**Response**:

```json
{
    "result": "success",
    "code": 200,
    "status": "ok",
    "screen": "documents_rejected", // This is unique for different `data`
    "next_screen": "",
    "message": "Successful",
    "data": {
       // `data` is always a json object with known fields and parameters
    }
}
```

I have data classes ready for different types of `data` responses like:

```kotlin
data class PhoneData(
        @SerializedName("phone_number")
        val phoneNumber: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("phone_status")
        val phoneStatus: String? = null
)
```

for `"screen": "phone"` and the following for another screen:

```kotlin
data class Data(
        val deepLink: String? = null
)
```

The problem is, at the start, I have to make the following request to retrieve the current screen:

```json
{
    "user_id": "user_id",
    "command": "get_current_screen",
}
```

which returns a similar response as above:

```json
{
    "result": "success",
    "code": 200,
    "status": "ok",
    "screen": "main_screen", // Different types of screen types are known.
    "next_screen": "",
    "message": "Successful",
    "data": {
       // `data` is always a json object but the object could contain anything depending on the `screen` type.
    }
}
```

but the data field could contain anything depending on the `screen`

```kotlin
data class SplashScreenData(
        // How do I make this data class combine all other data classes? One ugly approach is to add all the fields from different `data` classes here and use this one only.
)
```

I found about the RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory for polymorphic cases but am not sure how to make it work when there's no "type" like field within the `data` object (`screen` is unique but it's outside the data object).

It would be very helpful if someone has a solution or could point me in a direction.

Comment: Do you know what type data is when you make the call to get it?  If so, you can make the data's type a template parameter and parse it that way (you have to tell GSON what the template is).  If you don't know it but there's a fixed set of possibilities, you can write a custom deserializer that looks at the data and correctly deserializes it, but then data would probably need to be type Any.

Comment: No. I don't know the type when making the call. Yes, there's a fixed set of possibilities. Will try that, Thanks!

Comment: You can use `screen` parameter to deserialize or serialize the `data` object into its respective class.

Comment: Don't know why you didn't try to search before and save your and others time, but Gson has almost a built-in for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588020/gson-serialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects/22081826#22081826

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                val frameTextReceived: String = frame.readText()
                val jsonObject = JsonParser.parseString(frameTextReceived).asJsonObject
                val type = when (jsonObject.get("type").asString) {
                    TYPE_JOIN_ROOM -> JoinRoom::class.java
                    TYPE_GAME_MOVE -> GameMove::class.java
                    TYPE_DISCONNECT_REQUEST -> DisconnectRequest::class.java
                    else -> BaseModel::class.java
                }
                val payload = gson.fromJson(frameTextReceived, type)
```

This is my solution, here I have `type` parameter by which I can know in which class I have to deserialize the object but in your case you have `screen` parameter, you can use this.